# Setting up SSH Host [host]: Initializing VS Code Server hangs

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Just installed **Remote Development Extensions** for **VS Code Insiders**.

- Added this to settings:

  {
      "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal":true
  }
- Setup my ssh config file
- Ran `Remote-SSH: Connect to host` command
- Entered remote password (Note: these same ssh creds work in VSC)

I'm still waiting for VS Code Server to install...

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, works fine if I ssh "host" but not from the VS Code Extensions. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I have not returned to this problem because i've been coding locally for two months. but i'm now back to coding against the remote vm, so i'm motivated to try yet again.

Comment: first, to catch up on the thread: I installed powershell on the ubuntu vm, and remote debugging worked and has been working...until just this minute. now, connecting to remote hangs in VXS Code, and in Insiders edition I am getting the "process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe" exception.